# How to set highlight for tab labels when using MacVim?

Tags: macvim

By looking `:h hl-TabLine` I have the following hl groups:

[image]

But the actual colours are different, as you can see from the following image:

[image]

Reading `:h setting-guitablabel` didn't help too much.

Any hints?
Any idea on how to use the colours as shown in the first screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabLine`, `TablineFill`, and `TabLineSel` only apply to Vim's own text-based tabline, not to the tab widgets in your screenshot. They are handled by the GUI toolkit on which the MacVim GUI is based and there is no way to change how they look.

However, it is possible to force the MacVim GUI to use Vim's text-based tabline—which uses the highlight groups listed above—instead of the default GUI tabs by removing `e` from `:help 'guioptions'`:

```
:set guioptions-=e
```

[image: tabs]